# What are the side effects of `exec sp_updatestats` command?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

> Timeout expired.The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server is not responding

I got a timeout error executing a query. I searched some solution from google and stackoverflow. Some suggested to execute the command using `exec sp_updatestats` to solve the problem, but some are recommending to avoid `exec sp_updatestats` command.

What are the side effects of `exec sp_updatestats` command?

Comment: Where do you execute your query, in your client applivation? All that you need is to configure another timeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, according to the documentation the [sp_updatestats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-updatestats-transact-sql) does somethings of things when you run it.

> **sp_updatestats** executes UPDATE STATISTICS, by specifying the ALL keyword, on all user-defined and internal tables in the database. **sp_updatestats** displays messages that indicate its progress. When the update is completed, it reports that statistics have been updated for all tables.
>   **sp_updatestats** updates statistics on disabled nonclustered indexes and does not update statistics on disabled clustered indexes.
>
> For disk-based tables, **sp_updatestats** updates only the statistics that require updating based on the modification_counter information in the *sys.dm_db_stats_properties* catalog view, thus avoiding unnecessary updates of statistics on unchanged rows. Statistics on memory-optimized tables are always updated when executing **sp_updatestats**. Therefore do not execute **sp_updatestats** more than necessary.
>
> sp_updatestats can trigger a recompile of stored procedures or other compiled code. However, sp_updatestats might not cause a recompile, if only one query plan is possible for the tables referenced and the indexes on them. A recompilation would be unnecessary in these cases even if statistics are updated.
>
> For databases with a compatibility level below 90, executing **sp_updatestats** does not preserve the latest NORECOMPUTE setting for specific statistics. For databases with a compatibility level of 90 or higher, **sp_updatestats** does preserve the latest NORECOMPUTE option for specific statistics.

To resolve the timeout error you shouldn't call this function in your stored procedures, you should investigate using an Execution Plan what's happening in that query and what are the bottlenecks. Create the missing indexes and then review the Execution Plan again.

That function should be called from a maintenance plan once in a while, not from your sps of udfs.